# How to count the most frequent character from various strings inputted inside a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a code that finds the most frequent letter/character used (including special characters like . , / ), while allowing the user to keep inputting new inputs until he/she enters a "!". I wrote the following, but it only counts the most frequent letter in the last string inputted. Does anyone know how I can fix it so that it counts the most frequently used letter out of all of the inputs? Thanks!

Update: I solved the issue by adding all the inputs to a list, converting the list to a string and finding the most common value in the string. No idea if there's something more efficient, but this worked!

```
while w.count != 2:
    w = input("Enter here: ")
    w.count("!")
    max_letter = w[0]
    min_letter = w[0]
    max = w.count(w[0])
    min = w.count(w[0])
    for char in w:
            if char is not " ":
                if w.count(char) > max:
                        max_letter = char
                        max = w.count(char)
print(max,max_letter)
```

Comment: try putting your `min`, `max` initialisation before the `while` loop then update these value at every cycle if they need to be.

Comment: My print statement is actually inside; I spaced it wrong in my question- sorry! It still resets after each while loop. I have a bunch of character counters inside the while loop, like "if letter == "a": a_counter +=1", and those do not reset, but the max_letter thing always resets. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the print statement inside the `while` loop.

```
while w.count != 2:
    w = input("Enter here: ")
    w.count("!")
    max_letter = w[0]
    min_letter = w[0]
    max = w.count(w[0])
    min = w.count(w[0])
    for char in w:
            if char is not " ":
                if w.count(char) > max:
                        max_letter = char
                        max = w.count(char)
    print(max,max_letter)
```

Comment: I actually have a bunch of counters between "w = input(...)" and "print(max,max_letter)", so the those counters keep counting after each while loop, but the max letter always resets. :( My print statement is actually inside; I typed it wrong in my question- sorry!